# Migrating from XMM to YMM

Tags: assembly, masm, sse, simd, avx

Consider:

```
movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [rcx]
movdqa xmm1, xmmword ptr [rcx + 16]
movdqa xmm2, xmmword ptr [rcx + 32]
movdqa xmm3, xmmword ptr [rcx + 48]
```

The above code works fine. `rcx` is an address of the first element of an array of 32-bit uints.

However, when trying to use `ymm` in a similiar fashion:

```
vmovdqa ymm0, ymmword ptr [rcx]
vmovdqa ymm1, ymmword ptr [rcx + 32]
```

The code randomly throws sigsegvs: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF95ACC102C (Asm.dll) in Asm.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`.

**Why, how can I make it work?**

My CPU is i5-10210u (supports AVX-256). Running in X64 Release/Debug.

Comment: Verify `rcx` value. That should not happen due to this change, the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Is `rcx` aligned to 32 bytes?  `movdqa xmm, m128` requires 16 byte alignment but `vmovdqa ymm, m256` requires 32 byte alignment.  Use `vmovdqu` to sidestep all alignment issues instead.  Contrary to SSE instructions, AVX instructions do not generally have alignment requirements (`vmovdqa` is one of the few exceptions).

Comment: @fuz May I ask how can I verify if `rcx` is 32 bytes aligned? In C++, I have `int32_t* ptr` that is passed as first argument to this procedure. Therefore I guess it should be aligned.

Comment: @Jester If that matters, it sometimes gives sigsegvs and sometimes does not. `rcx` value is fixed, does not change.

Comment: Also seems like `vmovdqu` always works, whereas `vmovdqa` "likely" fails.

Comment: That does sound like aligment problem then but the error message is misleading as it mentions address `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @weno Check if the address when converted to `uintptr_t` is dividable by 32.  Using `vmovdqa` instead is a valid solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks. The address is not divisible by 32. Can I do something about it?

Comment: @fuz:
`int32_t* graph = read("graph.txt");
std::cout << (uintptr_t) &graph[0] << std::endl;
the_asm_procedure(graph, graph_size);`

Prints `11468207942384` address which is divisible by 16, but not by 32.

Comment: `read` must allocate aligned memory for `graph` using the specialized memory allocation API, like `posix_memalign`, `memalign`, `_aligned_malloc`, or Boost.Align. Alternatively, you can use unaligned loads (`vmovdqu`), but you may pay performance penalty for unaligned memory accesses.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Thanks. I think I am going to change my implementation to use `int8_t` rather than `int32_t` anyway. Therefore I think the problem should be solved on its own. :)

Comment: @weno It doesn't matter what element type you use in a vector. As long as you load/store 256-bit vectors, either the memory locations need to be aligned to 32-byte boundary or you have to use unaligned load/store instructions. In VEX-encoded instructions, memory operands of instructions other than `vmovdqa` also need not be aligned.

Comment: @fuz: Do feel free to post your first comment as an answer, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is rcx aligned to 32 bytes? `movdqa xmm, m128` requires 16 byte alignment but `vmovdqa ymm, m256` requires 32 byte alignment, so if you just port the code to AVX2 without increasing the alignment, it won't work.

Either increase the alignment to 32 byte or use `vmovdqu` to sidestep all alignment issues instead. Contrary to SSE instructions, memory operands to AVX instructions generally do not have alignment requirements (`vmovdqa` is one of the few exceptions).  It is still a good idea to align your input data if possible as memory accesses crossing cache lines incur extra penalties.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory is aligned on a 64 byte boundary for 256-bit AVX operations?

Comment: `vmovdqa ymm, [mem]` "only" requires 32-byte alignment, the width of one YMM vector.  Also, only a very few AVX instructions require alignment, `vmovdqa` being one of them (that's what the `a` stands for).  Alignment is generally helps performance some and is recommended, but isn't essential for correctness if you avoid `vmovdqa` / `vmovaps`